# How can I transfer a file using MDP toward TWRP?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, mdp

I've been trying to install the Pixel Experience ROM. I reset my Samsung Galaxy S7, opened TWRP, and enabled MDP. However, when I open my File Explorer on my PC and open my system folder, nothing shows. "The folder is empty."

I'm trying to figure out how to move the folder `PixelExperience_Plus_herolte-10.0-20200927-1516-OFFICIAL.zip` over to the SD card mounted on the phone.

I hope you can help.
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have TWRP installed  ,  So I assume you already have ADB environment .

So the file PixelExperience_Plus_herolte-10.0-20200927-1516-OFFICIAL.zip is on you laptop , you can use **adb sideload** to load the file to the phone .

More info you can check this [link](https://twrp.me/faq/ADBSideload.html)